# How to find out the real name of mountable devices?

Tags: linux, mount, devices, nautilus

When I open Nautilus and I go to the other locations I can see my unmounted hdd wich name is /dev/sda1 and it's real name is HDD. How can I found the real name of /dev/sda1 from the command line?

Comment: Do you mean the label of the partition? I use **lsblk** to get a picture of my disk tree; here's the full command: `lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID`

Comment: sorry @ajgringo619, I didn't saw your comment when I posted my answer, I will leave it because `-f` might be easier to remember

Comment: No problem, @MunzirTaha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By real name, you mean the **LABEL**. This can be viewed with

`lsblk -f`

*or*

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`

*or*

`sudo blkid -o list`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I looked for.